# Bug using quote button in Google Chrome on Windows

Tags: bug, status-declined, editor, google-chrome

When highlighting text and using the quote button, the replaced text is incorrect.  It takes the end of the quote, and adds that as extra to both the beginning and the end of the replaced text, messing up the quote.  This text is quoted below as an example.

example.

example.> When highlighting text and using the

> quote button, the replaced text is
>   incorrect.  It takes the end of the
>   quote, and adds that as extra to both
>   the beginning and the end of the
>   replaced text, messing up the quote. 
>   This text is quoted below as an
>   example.example.

example.

---

I'm on Chrome 6.0.458.1 dev on Win7.  I've duplicated this on several of the sites (SO, MSO, as well as WA and WM).  No problems with Firefox 3.6 or IE8.

---

**EDIT**: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=56095

Comment: Same browser, same system, same bug.

Comment: Yep, made a video of the problem. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LsABVhOmzhc

Comment: Also repro on Linux and Windows with Chrome 7.

Comment: +1 repro on Chrome 7.0.544.0. Very annoying. :-\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No repro in the current version of Chrome (5.0.375.99).

> Alice was beginning to get very tired
>   of sitting by her sister on the bank,
>   and of having nothing to do: once or
>   twice she had peeped into the book her
>   sister was reading, but it had no
>   pictures or conversations in it, 'and
>   what is the use of a book,' thought
>   Alice 'without pictures or
>   conversation?'

For the record, we don't support unreleased beta browsers.

Comment: I just switched to the stable release (6.0.472.55), and the bug is still there.

Comment: @hmemcpy yep it's a bug in Chrome. No-repro in every other browser.

Comment: Reproduced in Chrome 6.0.472.63, Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I am getting the same bug on Chrome 6.0.472.62/Ubuntu 10.04.

This is really annoying... For some reason it was working fine but it's broken now. Anyone find a solution for this?