# Blockquote Editor Button Appears Broken

Tags: bug, status-norepro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bug using quote button in Google Chrome on Windows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56610/bug-using-quote-button-in-google-chrome-on-windows)

Using Google Chrome (haven't tested in other browsers), the Blockquote feature on the editor seems to duplicate text and do all sorts of other wackiness.

For example:

> 123
>
> 123> 123123

Is what I get when I type 123, highlight it, and click the blockquote button.

I also get this at the end of the post:

> 123

Comment: No repro in Chrome 5.0 (win), are you sure those are the exact repro steps?

Comment: No repro, Firefox 3.6.8 (mac).

Comment: I bet you're using a beta browser, aren't you? We don't support beta browsers..

Comment: Totally forgot I signed up for beta builds or else I'd have checked first. This is the very first problem I've had with them. Props to Google I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same problem yesterday (with blockquotes, bullet points, etc.) while using Chrome 6, which is in **beta**. As Jeff stated above, beta browsers aren't officially supported.

Other than that, it works in Chrome 5!