# Some time when I got upvoted two times I got only 2 points instead of 20. Why?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

Some time when I got upvoted two times I got only 2 points instead of 20. Why?

And the quote button is not working properly. I have informed the team, but still I can't see any resolution.

When I write `abc` and then quote it it converts it into

```
abc

abc> abcabc

abc
```

The team replied that it's a bug in Google Chrome.

Comment: Maybe you hit the daily rep limit of 200.

Comment: @Gamecat yes I did hit,but whats the significance of this rule ?

Comment: @Henk Holterman : removed LOL :p

Comment: what? you get points for upvoting? and how to upvote 2 times? I can only upvote once... :-)

Comment: concerning the quoting bug, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63307/blockquote-glitch-in-editor-in-chrome-6-and-7). You should however only post one issue per question since they are in fact independent of each other

Comment: @Tobais Kienzler  I amusing chrome 6.0.472.62, and it is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because you hit the daily reputation cap.  Once you hit the cap of 200 any further up votes do not increase your reputation.

[How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Regarding the quote bug - you will have to wait for this bug to be fixed in Chrome.

Comment: ok3 more to go..

Comment: With a reputation of 113, I find it a bit odd that OP would have hit the daily reputation cap. Or OP has multiple accounts.

Comment: @Joris - OP has multiple Accounts.  Probably talking about their SO account.  Check out the Accounts tab on the user profile http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150595?tab=accounts#tab-top