# Blockquoting does not work in the WMD editor

Tags: bug, editor, blockquote

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Blockquote glitch in editor in Chrome 6 and 7](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63307/blockquote-glitch-in-editor-in-chrome-6-and-7)

Here's a screenshot:
[image: screenshot of improperly blockquoted text with multiple instances of the last word before and after the quote]

The highlighted text is what I wanted to surround in `<blockquote>` tags. It happens 100% of the time.

**Browser:** Google Chrome 7.0.517

**OS:** Windows 7

Comment: Shame on you for reporting a known browser bug and expecting SO to do something about it. You are a terrible person. Wait - that's not my line... I mean, WHY WON'T THEY FIX THIS! That's more like it.

Comment: @jon can you fix some bugs in Windows for me? Oh, those aren't your responsibility? That's what I thought...

Comment: @Jeff - It's my responsibility to make my software work around bugs in Windows (and 3rd party components).