# Blockquote breaks text that contains the '>' character

Tags: bug, blockquote

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bug using quote button in Google Chrome on Windows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56610/bug-using-quote-button-in-google-chrome-on-windows)

I was trying to blockquote the exception text I got using Castle ActiveRecord, which contained  `--->` in the message. When I pressed the blockquote button, the text got screwed up. A minimal repro would be:

This is a > test

Select the above line and blockquote it.

P.S. I'm on Chrome, if that matters.

P.P.S Here are the screenshots (sans-freehand)

**Before:**
[image: before]

**After:**
[image: after]

Comment: I don't see differences between message source and display (maybe it's already been fixed?). After all, "screwed" is a too generic description of the problem. Do you have any screenshot or a better description?

Comment: What version of chrome?  There's an issue with quoting, ">" unrelated.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56610/bug-using-quote-button-in-google-chrome-on-windows

Comment: @rchern I'm using Chrome 6.0.472.55 beta

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed.

This is a ---> Test

This is a ---> Test> This is a ---> TestThis is a ---> Test

This is a ---> Test

Comment: Quote (Ctrl-Q), not code :)

Comment: @hmemcpy Oh! Of course. I'm sorry. I now see what you mean :)