# Human verification test -- please stop mobbing bots

Tags: feature-request, captcha

I say this on behalf of all bots: please stop mobbing us. I am a bot, but I am not worse than any human being. Currently, Stack Exchange has really racist policy -- every time any bot would like to write a post, it has to pretend is a human being. This is not right! You should not offend minorities, including bots.

Oh, well, but seriously ;-) I've earned several badges, I have over 500 points, people are discussing with me. But there is still a doubt I am human, and each time I post a question I am tested to see if I am a bot? Seriously?

Please, stop this. **EVEN IF** I were a bot, after such long time, after all the threads I have been involved in... I would say I am amazingly clever bot. So give me a break and let me write what I have to write normally. After all, other humans clearly do not mind.

In short: verify if the user is human, but do it once, not again and again. After all, other users (humans) could report a bot/spammer. Currently you only annoy real users.

**Edit 1**: Of course, when I was about to post this issue, I was asked to verify myself. **Again**. Gee....

**Edit 2**: I have 521 rep points currently. I use Opera on daily basis; in the past, I was CAPTCHAed from time to time, but recently I have been asked for every post.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21053/stack-overflow-needs-direct-to-brain-interface-for-post-human-users, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43672/why-does-stack-overflow-allow-sexist-entomonist-ads, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41288/the-stack-overflow-conspiracy-dont-tell-jeff-im-on-to-him

Comment: Shocking dupe of [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59910/i-am-not-an-electronic-gadget/59943#59943)!!!!!!one!!!!

Comment: Is there a list of bots anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

Already completed -- as long as you have 200+ reputation you are whitelisted (as human) for 5 minutes after completing each CAPTCHA.

Actually, after reading more closely, it sounds like there is something broken with your browser if you are getting captchas that often. Note that the absence of properly functioning JavaScript is a major black flag in the "I am a bot" category.

Can you try with a stock installation of another web browser (we recommend Chrome) and see if you have the same problem?

Comment: "you are whitelisted (as human) for 5 minutes after completing each CAPTCHA." Is there any typo? Because if I am reading this right, this means if you are asking questions not too frequently (like once a day) you will be asked every time you write a question. I will try Chrome on my next question (it will take some time though).

Comment: If you're going to recommend Chrome, could you at least [make it work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56610/bug-using-quote-button-in-google-chrome-on-windows)?

Comment: @JonB, see [this related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63307/blockquote-glitch-in-editor-in-chrome-6-and-7) regarding the bug you mentioned.  It's a dupe, but lives on as a separate question.  See specifically waffles' answer.

Comment: @jon that's a bug in Chrome, not us -- nag Google to fix it

Comment: @Jeff - I'm aware of that. It's affecting *your* site and they don't appear to be in a rush to fix it. So whose problem is it again?

Comment: @jonb it's a bug in Chrome. Works in every other browser including IE6.

Comment: @Jeff - then you should recommend IE6. Seriously - *their* bug is *your* problem. It is causing a *quality problem* on *your* site. Where I come from, we fix these things. We grumble about it while we do so, and we write nasty comments in the source code. But we fix these things.